# Break after Text in td

Tags: javascript, html

I want you to edit the text,
it is not provided with div but with `<br>` and that it is then identified by another function.
But somehow that doesn't work, it keeps getting created with multiple line-breaks (`<br>`).
Please help me in this situation.

Here is the Code:

```
        function editCells() {
            editorMode = !editorMode;
            let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.row_lessons td');
            let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

            cells.forEach(function (cell) {
                if (editorMode) {
                    cell.contentEditable = "true"; 
                    editor.textContent = 'Stop editing';
                    cell.style.textAlign = 'left';
            
                    cell.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
                        if (event.key === "Enter") {
                            cell.style.textAlign = 'left';
                            event.preventDefault();

                           
                            const cellT = cell.textContent;
                            const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                            const br = document.createElement('br');
                            range.insertNode(br);

                           
                            cellT.setStartAfter(br);
                            range.setEndAfter(br);

                            
                            this.focus()
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    cell.style.textAlign = 'center';
                    cell.contentEditable = "false"; 
                    editor.textContent = 'Edit cells';

                    exitEditorMode();
                }
            });
            if (!editorMode) {
                applyClassesBasedOnKeywords();
            }
        };
```

I try so that there are no multi breaks and that the cursor stays where it should be and that it doesn't wander off somewhere.

Comment: `cellT` is a string, it doesn't have `setStartAfter` method. Probably you need `range.setStartAfter`. If that doesn't fix your issue, you've to provide a [mre], as [a simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/b27wkp93/) based on your code doesn't behave like you've described.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)